Wordpress Hideo Theme
I want to ask if someone understands WordPress, I changed my theme to "Hideo theme", isn't it that when changing the theme, the content of the new theme will overwrite the old content? If it doesn't overwrite the old content, how do I get the content from the Hideo theme to be on my website? I just want to change the content with my content and not recreate the appearance of the website from scratch.
How to get the content from the Hideo Theme, i want the content and later i just change it with my content, not build website from the scratch
